# Sorting csv data by headers but getting IndexError

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

It seems that my code fails when I try to set what headers/columns of data I want to use giving me an index error when trying to parse headers

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
import math, datetime
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing , cross_validation, svm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pickle

style.use('ggplot')
df = pd.read_csv('convertcsv.csv',sep='\t')

df = np.array(df)

print(df)


df = df[['Open','High','Low','Close','Volume (BTC)']]
print("ok")

df['HL_PCT'] = (df['High'] - df['Close']) / df['Close'] * 100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Close'] - df['Open']) / df['Open'] * 100.0

df = df[['Close','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Volume (BTC)']]

forecast_col = 'Close'
df.fillna(-999999, inplace=True)

forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01*len(df)))


df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)



X = np.array(df.drop(['label'],1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]
X = X[:-forecast_out:]


df.dropna(inplace=True)
y = np.array(df['label'])




X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.2)


clf = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
with open('linearregression.pickle','wb') as f:
pickle.dump(clf, f)

pickle_in = open('linearregression.pickle','rb')
clf =pickle.load(pickle_in)


accuracy = clf.score(X_test,y_test)
print(accuracy)


forecast_set = clf.predict(X_lately)




df['Forecast'] = np.nan

last_date = df.iloc[-1].name

last_unix = last_date.timestamp()
one_day = 86400
next_unix = last_unix + one_day

for i in forecast_set:
    next_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(next_unix)
    next_unix += one_day
    df.loc[next_date] = [np.nan for _ in range(len(df.columns)-1)] + [i]


df['Close'].plot()
df['Forecast'].plot()
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.pause(1)
plt.show()
print("we done?")`
...
```

I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong, it worked with the previous data set I was using, if it helps here is the format of the csv file that I was pulling from:

```
Timestamp,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume (BTC),Volume (Currency),Weighted Price
2017-09-30 00:00:00,4162.04,4177.63,4154.28,4176.08,114.81,478389.12,4166.96
2017-09-30 01:00:00,4170.84,4224.6,4170.84,4208.14,348.45,1463989.18,4201.4
```

I am not too experienced with this sort of stuff, and I tried to find other people with the same error but everyone was having a different sort of problem, I can include more data if it is needed.

Comment: No. Mark the answer as correct and ask your second question as a separate question. This is a big no no on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're converting your dataframe to a numpy array with df = np.array(df).

Don't expect a numpy array to function as a pandas dataframe.

Remove

```
df = np.array(df)
```

and you should be able to slice your matrix by column name with

```
df = df[['Open','High','Low','Close','Volume (BTC)']]
```